OpenID configuration JSON contains unrecognized host to internal client
I'm using Keycloak to hosted with with portal.local/auth. I've proved that my setup is working when I use a Spring Boot application hosted in localhost. So, localhost:8080 app can connect to portal.local/auth/realms/myshop issuer and can perform auth code flow authentication.
The problem is when the app is deployed into the same cluster with the keycloak in Kubernetes. The app is configured using keycloak internal name which is keycloak.svc so that the issuer address would be keycloak.svc/auth/realms/myshop. The configuration JSON of this issuer still shows portal.local instead of keycloak.svc, hence it's not recognized by the application.
What's the correct way to configure they app or the keycloak in this situation? This is my Helm configuration when installing oci://registry-1.docker.io/bitnamicharts/keycloak
auth:
  adminUser: admin
  adminPassword: admin

extraEnvVars:
  - name: KEYCLOAK_LOG_LEVEL
    value: DEBUG

  - name: PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING
    value: "true"

postgresql:
  postgresqlPassword: postgresPwd

volumes:
  # To import *.json
  - ./import:/opt/bitnami/keycloak/data/import
  # To export, go inside container then run `kc.sh export --dir /export/ --users realm_file`
  - ./export:/export


httpRelativePath: /auth/

ingress:
  enabled: true
  hostname: portal.local

resources:
  requests:
    memory: "512Mi"
    cpu: "500m"

  limits:
    memory: "1Gi"
    cpu: "1"


The most important thing is to have the following configuration in the client application deployed within k8s:
#  # This CAN'T be used when internal connection to Keycloak is also required e.g. in K8s
#- name: SPRING_SECURITY_OAUTH2_CLIENT_PROVIDER_MYSHOP_ISSUERURI
#  value: http://auth-keycloak/auth/realms/myshop

  # 1) The URI to redirect to for login (done at browser)
- name: SPRING_SECURITY_OAUTH2_CLIENT_PROVIDER_MYSHOP_AUTHORIZATIONURI
  value: http://portel.local/auth/realms/myshop/protocol/openid-connect/auth

  # 2) Needed
- name: SPRING_SECURITY_OAUTH2_CLIENT_PROVIDER_MYSHOP_TOKENURI
  value: http://auth-keycloak/auth/realms/myshop/protocol/openid-connect/token

  # Required for confidential client
- name: SPRING_SECURITY_OAUTH2_CLIENT_REGISTRATION_MYSHOP_CLIENTSECRET
  value: O2Cv7BzzkllEySdxFrpJO6ydxNIEJ9BF

  # 3) The URI to redirect to on auth result (done at browser)
- name: SPRING_SECURITY_OAUTH2_CLIENT_REGISTRATION_MYSHOP_REDIRECTURI
  value: http://portel.local/login/oauth2/code/classic-app

  # 4) Required in post successful login
- name: SPRING_SECURITY_OAUTH2_CLIENT_PROVIDER_MYSHOP_JWKSETURI
  value: http://auth-keycloak/auth/realms/myshop/protocol/openid-connect/certs

